# Does an array of promises only start executing once passed to promise all?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

If an array of promises are built and then passed to `Promise.all` does execution start immediately or only once `Promise.all` is called?

Example code:

```
let promises: Promise<string> [] = [this.methodCall(), this.methodCall(), this.methodCall()];

 Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
  ...
 }).catch(error => {
  ...
 });
```

Also, would this code example catch all rejections?

Comment: On your second question... maybe just read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)? *It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.*

Comment: "it rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects", I assume that means it still handles the other promise rejections.

Comment: `Promise.all()`, like any other promise functions, will return only a single result of type either resolve or reject. So once any one of the promises passed to `Promise.all()` gets rejected it will immediately return with the rejection and you should not wait or expect any other resolutions whatsoever. If you need to handle the rejections separately then you may need to sequence your promises by some other means like reducing or alike.

Comment: Could `Promise.all()` lead to a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`, since multiple promises could reject?

Comment: I "guess" `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` and `Uncaught (in promise)` might be the same thing (node vs chrome) and this may not apply for the left over rejecting promises in `Promise.all()`. It's about you are not `.catch()`ing a rejection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `Promise` is created, it starts to work immediately. See the logs. Promise body function works, then after 5 seconds starts the `Promise.all`.

```js
const pr = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('Started !!!');
  resolve();
});

console.log('Before setTimeout');

setTimeout( () => {
  Promise.all([pr]).then(result => console.log('Resolved !!!'));
}, 5000)

console.log('After setTimeout');
```

From the [**Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

> A function that is passed with the arguments resolve and reject. The
>   executor function is executed immediately by the Promise
>   implementation, passing resolve and reject functions (the executor is
>   called before the Promise constructor even returns the created
>   object).